# Multiple outlets in Ember.js v2 router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just getting started with Ember.js and one thing that seems promising is the idea of multiple outlets combining multiple templates mixed together to produce a complex but modular layout.

I can't get it to work, though. It seems like there were many questions, answers, and examples on this a few months ago (mid 2012) but in the march to 1.0 they very recently (December 2012/January 2013) rewrote the router to a "v2" API. The docs are good at what they do describe but omit a lot of big picture context, and I have yet to find a single end-to-end example.

Here's what I've read:

- everything under [the Routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) (up to date, but not exhaustive)
- ["outlet" template helper api reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet) (this may be out of date? Every attempt I've made to call `controller.connectOutlet()` fails with `Uncaught TypeError: Object <(generated animals.cats controller):ember170> has no method 'connectOutlet'`.
- announcement of [Ember.js Router API v2](https://gist.github.com/3981133). Specifically the bottom couple comments (question and answer on multiple outlets). Yes, this gist is marked "Warning; outdated; for up-to-date information see the routing guide". But the current routing guide doesn't seem to completely describe the behavior. The [Rendering a template](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) section of the guide shows how to render to different outlets that already exist (and I can get this to work), but I can't figure out how to connect additional outlets or instantiate additional templates.

What does work for me:

- Setting up nested routes (well, nested resources; you can't nest routes; but you can customize routes for the nested resources), and nesting templates and outlets that are automatically instantiated according to the routes.

What I have not been able to figure out how to accomplish:

- Manually instantiate templates and connect them to outlets. This seems necessary if you want to use multiple outlets, or if you want to have a structure your outlet/template relationships differently than your routes. (There will be an example of this below. Essentially what I'm trying to do is use a template as a mixin that I can embed wherever else I want.)

The thing that seems promising but fails for me is

- Override a route's controller (extend the route using `App.WhateverRoute = Ember.Route.extend()`, supply my own `setupController` method) and call `controller.connectOutlet` here. This fails as described above; the controller object passed into this method does not have a `connectOutlet` method.

Example ([here as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metamatt/CP5QU/1/), or below as a self-contained html document which embeds the CSS and scripts and loads Ember and dependencies from https links, so you should be able to just save to a local file and open in a browser if you want to try it):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Ember.js Router Example</title>
    <style>
      .outlet {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/1.0.rc.2/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js"></script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <p>Root index template. You should not see this because we redirect App.IndexRoute elsewhere.</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
      <p>About this demo.</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="guide">
      <p>Guide to this demo.</p>
    </script>

   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="animals">
      <p>Animals. You have selected:</p>
      <div class='outlet'>{{ outlet }}</div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="animals/index">
      <!-- you will not see this unless you disable App.AnimalsIndexRoute redirect. -->
      <p>No animal selected.</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="animals/cats">
      <p>Cat. I can meow. Like all animals, I
        <span class='outlet'>{{ outlet }}</span>
      </p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="animals/dogs">
      <p>Dog. I can bark. Like all animals, I
        <span class='outlet'>{{ outlet }}</span>
      </p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="animal_mixin">
      <p>am alive.</p>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          Select contents for my outlet:
          {{#linkTo "index"}}/ (root){{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo "about"}}/about{{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo "guide"}}/guide{{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo "animals"}}/animals{{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo "animals.cats"}}/animals/cats{{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo "animals.dogs"}}/animals/dogs{{/linkTo}}
        </p>

        <div class='outlet'>
          {{ outlet }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script>
      App = Ember.Application.create();
      App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource("about");
        this.resource("guide");
        this.resource("animals", function() {
          this.route("cats");
          this.route("dogs");
        })
      });
      App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        redirect: function() {
          this.transitionTo('about');
        }
      });
      App.AnimalsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        redirect: function() {
          this.transitionTo('animals.cats');
        }
      });
      App.AnimalsCatsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller, model) {
          // BUG: this controller object has no connectOutlet method
          // (uncomment to see this yourself)
          // controller.connectOutlet('animal_mixin');
        }
      });
      App.initialize();
    </script>

</html>
```

Essentially animal_mixin is a chunk of boilerplate that I want to use repeatedly as a mixin, dropping it wherever I want by putting an outlet there and connecting it to this template. I realize this example is contrived, because I could do it with "inheritance" provided by the nesting structure: the contents of animal_mixin could go directly in the "animals" template, and I wouldn't need to mention it in animals/cats and animals/dogs. That would be fine if I wanted it in all animals, but let's say I had another subroute of /animals that I don't want to include this snippet. Again, the example is contrived but I hope the question and the intent are clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple named outlets. Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/W2dE4/6/.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet header}}
    {{outlet body}}
    {{outlet navBar}}
</script>
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456215/ember-js-pre4-how-to-do-the-previous-pre2-connectoutlet-stuff) for some other techniques.

```
events: {
    showModal: function(){
        this.render('modal', {
            into: 'index',
            outlet: 'modalOutlet',
            controller: this.controllerFor('modal')
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. You can call this.render() multiple times in the same renderTemplate() handler. Seems obvious in retrospect but that had not occurred to me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify when the dom for outlet header is rendered?  Is it rerendered each time you switch posts?  Also, do you need to call this.render('header') in every single route's renderTemplate?

Comment: Hi Yoh, named outlets are only re-rendered when specifically over-written. In general, you should stick close to the conventions of nesting resources and routes in parallel, rendering relevant named {{outlets}}. You should only call this.render('template') if you want to over-write the default template (which is, by default, the route, model, and controller name). Check ember.js guides and api docs (emberjs.com/api) for specific guidance. No need to downvote an answer to a specific question that was answered correctly. If you have a new question, feel free to post a new topic.