# EmberJS multiple yield helper

Tags: templates, ember.js, yield

I have a custom view that I've created in Ember.  I really love the `{{yield}}` helper to allow me to control the 'bread' of the sandwich.  However, what I'd like to do now, is create a 'double decker' sandwich, and have a view with more than 1 yield in it, or at the very least be able to parameterize which template to use in the 2nd yield.

so for example:

### layout.hbs

```
<div>
    <div class="header">Header Content</div>
    <div class="tab1">
        Tab 1 Controls.
        <input type="text" id="common1" />
        {{yield}}
    </div>
    <div class="tab2">
        Tab 2 Controls.
        <input type="text" id="common2" />
        {{yield second-template}} or {{template second-template}}
    </div>
</div>
```

### app.js

```
App.MyDoubleDeckerView = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName:"layout',
    templateName:"defaultTemplate", 
    "second-template":"defaultSecond"
});

App.MyExtendedDoubleDecker = App.MyDoubleDeckerView({
    templateName:"myTemplate", 
    "second-template":"mySecondTemplate"
});
```

is there any way of doing something like this?  What I love about the views in ember is the ability to centralize & extend views which allows me to keep the things that are common among all the views in one place...

Comment: Why not to use `ContainerView` instead?

Comment: From what I can tell you can't use ContainerView declaratively in the templates... is that right?

Comment: I found a work around using some jQuery.  I define my stuff for the 2nd tab in a div, then use appendTo to move it over to the 2nd tab in the didInsertElement object... not pretty but it works

Comment: `ContainerView` is really an array of views and you can add views to it in imperative way if required. Check out http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html#sts=Ember.ContainerView%20Class%20packages/ember-views/lib/views/container_view.js:16 "Adding a view" section. The regular `pushObject` is appending new views. In your case you would like to nest a container view in another view to acts as its template.

Comment: I answered a similar problem here. Let me know if its helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841947/custom-components-with-multiple-yield-like-sections/21590775#21590775

Comment: @ben have you found an answer for this? If so, I encourage you self-answer and to close this issue :)

Comment: @Ben I wonder if you would mind taking a look at this discussion over here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/handlebars-block-helper-based-on-templating-language-twig/5051/12 because it might be what you're looking for? 
Alternatively, I wonder if multiple outlets might be what you're after?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531956/multiple-outlets-in-ember-js-v2-router

Answer (score 1):

As of Ember 3.25 you can use so called "named blocks" (see the Passing multiple blocks subsection of https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/modules/@glimmer%2Fcomponent).

Example component:

```
<h1>{{yield to="title"}}</h1>
{{yield}}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<PersonProfile @person={{this.currentUser}}>
  <:title>{{this.currentUser.name}}</:title>
  <:default>{{this.currentUser.siganture}}</:default>
</PersonProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use named outlets for this

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

### layout.hbs

```
<div>
    <div class="header">Header Content</div>
    <div class="tab1">
        Tab 1 Controls.
        <input type="text" id="common1" />
        {{yield}}
    </div>
    <div class="tab2">
        Tab 2 Controls.
        <input type="text" id="common2" />
        {{view "view.secondView"}}
    </div>
</div>
```

### app.js

```
App.MyDoubleDeckerView = Ember.View.extend({
    layoutName:"layout',
    templateName:"defaultTemplate", 
    secondView: Ember.view.extend({
        templateName: "defaultSecond"
    })
});

App.MyExtendedDoubleDecker = App.MyDoubleDeckerView({
    templateName:"myTemplate", 
    secondView: Ember.view.extend({
        templateName: "mySecondTemplate"
    });
});
```

In other words, invoke a view given by `view.secondView` from within your template. Then, set the `secondView` property in your class or subclass.

You could add a bit of syntactic sugar with

```
App.viewForTemplateName = function(templateName) {
    return Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: templateName
    });
};
```

Then, in your view definitions above, do

```
secondView: App.viewForTemplateName('mySecondTemplate')
```