# ember.js v1.0.0-rc.1 -- Using a modal outlet, how do I route out of the modal on close?

Tags: ember.js, modal-dialog, outlet

I'm attempting to render all my modals through application routing, but I'm having trouble figuring out the proper way to return to a previous state after I dismiss the modal.

Here's the basic setup:

I have an outlet in my application template which I'm using to display modal dialogs.

It looks something like:

```
{{ outlet modal }}
```

In my route mappings, I've defined hooks for the individual modal. For instance, my help dialog pops up with:

```
App.HelpRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this.render({ outlet: 'modal' });
    }
});
```

Right now, I can display my modal through the uri:

```
   foo.com/#/help
```

I have a hook to dismiss the modal using jQuery:

```
$('#modalHelpWindow').modal('hide');
```

But this doesn't really help, because I'm just hiding the element. I need to update URI on dismissal. If I hit the same route again, the modal is already hidden, and doesn't display.

What methods should I be using to dismiss the modal, and route the application back to its previous state? Should I just be using history.back()?

Note, I am aware of this SO question, but the solution is not the preferred 'ember' way of doing things, as programmatically created views will not have their controllers associated properly  [What's the right way to enter and exit modal states with Ember router v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327949/whats-the-right-way-to-enter-and-exit-modal-states-with-ember-router-v2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can hook up the hidden handler to do a history.back() call in my view's didInsertElement method, a la:

```
   didInsertElement: function() {
        var $me = this.$();
        $me.modal({backdrop:"static"});
        $me.on('hidden', function() {
            history.back();
        });
    },
```