# Transition to a route mantaining the previous content in ember

Tags: ember.js

I've a generic route `/login` that displays the login form inside a modal. Now I want the content behind to remain the same of the previous url.

How do you go about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Trying to implement login modal form as a generic `/login` route is probably not the best option, as it does not go well with the way Ember routes work, which can be summarised as follows:

- Given url is matched to (possibly multiple nested) routes.
- Each matched route resolves it's `model` and then renders corresponding templates to appropriate `outlets`. Templates for previous route are wiped out.

Navigating to generic `/login` would wipe out the templates rendered by previous route - namely there would be no content in the modal background (see also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035385/emberjs-modals-on-a-route)).

I would suggest either:

1. Not rendering `/login` route in modal dialog, but instead in the main app `outlet`, and only then redirecting user to the previous route. UI experience is probably not much worse as user probably does not need any information from the modal background anyway.
2. Instead of having generic `/login` route, you could use query parameter, e.g. `?should_login=true` on `ApplicationController` which would render login modal in appropriate outlet. This way *primary* application state would still be encapsulated in the route url, thus templates for the previous would be properly rendered in the modal background. Suggested approach on how to handle modal dialog can be found [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/).